# How to "cheat" the version number of Mac OS for iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Apple released iPhone SDK for Mac OS 10.6.x and I only have 10.5 and have no plans to upgrade, so I wonder how can I trick for latest iPhone SDK the version number that is 10.6?

Comment: going out on a limb here, but I'm guessing you'll have to figure out how to get your hackintosh upgraded.  But, in answer to your original question, sorry, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you will find that the reason for the minimum version requirement is that the iPhone SDK uses features that exist only on 10.6, and will not run correctly on 10.5.

Comment: This is correct.  Xcode 3.2 and later requires Snow Leopard, due to new OS features it uses.  I highly recommend upgrading to Snow Leopard for the new Xcode, if only for built-in access for the Clang Static Analyzer.